# VBA button click working sometimes

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, automation

I'm just getting started with VBA and I was following a simple tutorial to use VBA to make a Google Search in IE.

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.busy
DoEvents 'wait for page to finish loading
Wend
IE.Document.All("q").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
IE.Document.All("btnK").Click
End Sub
```

I ran this code multiple times (by pressing f5) and it appears that `IE.Document.All("btnK").Click` only works sometimes.
Sometimes the [Macros pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8FWV.png) will appear, sometimes not.
I was just wondering what could be the cause of this or if there's anyway to prevent this from happening.

I am using Excel 2013

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes pops up? You see that box when running the code?

Comment: The pop up only comes up sometimes when I press f5. When it pops up I have to click "run" to begin the marco. When it doesn't pop up, the macro will simply run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the search button altogether and concatenate the search term into the URL direct. For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim IE As Object, searchTerm As String
    searchTerm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .navigate "https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&source=hp&ei=XiooW8rAKMeZsgGji57gBw&q=" & searchTerm & "&oq=" & searchTerm & "&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i131k1j0l2j0i131k1j0j0i131k1l3.1481.2118.0.2518.7.6.0.0.0.0.124.555.0j5.6.0..3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.6.657.6..35i39k1.103.n22OrWdTQrs"
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
     Stop '<= Delete this line
    .Quit
     End With
End Sub
```

If you do an example search you can capture the URL and the edit in your variable name to string, as I show above.

As @RyszardJędraszyk explains (many thanks), you may have a dynamically loaded webpage in which content is not available at the moment you try to grab hold of an element. In this case you can have a loop which attempts to set to an element that you know should be present and loop while is nothing (with timeout).

Ryszard further points out you are missing your `ReadyState = 4` fully loaded (which does mean a dynamic page, for example, is actually fully loaded, or that a lazy-loading page has all items visible (you may require scrolling to achieve this. My answer above shows you how to also use the `ReadyState`.

I was unsure about the cause of this pop-up, so I just went with the simplest route to get the page of interest, to try and lessen the risk of this happening. It is not something I have ever had happen or could reproduce I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand what you're doing but I would like to know the underlining cause of why "Click" only works sometimes, or I just happen to be unlucky.

Comment: @Jummi You don't check `ReadyState` property of `IE` object in `DoEvents` loop. 4 means fully loaded.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk So I modified my code to have `While IE.busy Or IE.Readystate < 4` but this doesn't appear to correct the issue.

Comment: @Jummi Sometimes JavaScript loads on the page as well. Neither `Busy` nor `ReadyState` keep a track of it. Try adding 5 second wait before `IE.Document.All("q").Value` line, `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))` If with this line code always executes successfully, then it is JS fault.

Comment: Jummi - Ryszard has given you an excellent couple of explanation points. I guess I should have mentioned these in my hurry to bypass them. I will update.

Comment: Thank you your help. After some further testing it appears that my IE is the problem as it never goes into READYSTATE (it looks forever when I try to debug). Possibly because I have IE 11. For a simple google search your solution works well.